# FindComponent + set invalid challenge

Tags: java, primefaces

I have a this simplified form to show the challenge:

[image]

It is a form with multiple tabs (2 in this MVCE).

My goal is to highlight both fields in case of validation failure (but only for tab it is failing for).

### TabView (backing bean)

```java
package betlista.so.pf.findComponent;

import com.sun.faces.component.visit.FullVisitContext;
import org.primefaces.PrimeFaces;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.component.UIInput;
import javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot;
import javax.faces.component.visit.VisitCallback;
import javax.faces.component.visit.VisitContext;
import javax.faces.component.visit.VisitResult;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

@Component
public class TabView {

    List<TabData> tabData = new LinkedList<>();

    {
        tabData.add(new TabData("name 1", "val1-a", null));
        tabData.add(new TabData("name b", "val1-b", "val2-b"));
    }

    public List<TabData> getTabsData() {
        return tabData;
    }

    public void save() {
        boolean isValid = isValid();
        if (isValid) {
            // continue ...
        }
    }

    private boolean isValid() {
        boolean isOk = isOk();
        if (isOk) {
            return true;
        }
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Not saved!");
        message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addMessage(null, message);

        final UIViewRoot viewRoot = context.getViewRoot();
        List<UIInput> componentList = new LinkedList<>();
        viewRoot.visitTree(new FullVisitContext(context), new VisitCallback() {
            @Override
            public VisitResult visit(VisitContext context, UIComponent target) {
                if (target != null) {
                    final String id = target.getId();
                    if ("val1".equals(id) || "val2".equals(id)) {
                        if (target instanceof UIInput) {
                            componentList.add((UIInput) target);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return VisitResult.ACCEPT;
            }
        });
        for (UIInput uiInput: componentList) {
            uiInput.setValid(false);
        }
        context.validationFailed();
        PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("form");
        final UIComponent val1 = context.getViewRoot().findComponent("val1");
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isOk() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

in this simplified version `isOk()` returns `false`.

In a validation I know whether data for 1st or second tab is not ok and I'm trying to find a way how to highlight those two fields in tab.

I tried initially `context.getViewRoot().findComponent(...)`, but I'm not able to "find it" (returns  `null`). So to have access to the components I used this:

```java
        List<UIInput> componentList = new LinkedList<>();
        viewRoot.visitTree(new FullVisitContext(context), new VisitCallback() {
            @Override
            public VisitResult visit(VisitContext context, UIComponent target) {
                if (target != null) {
                    final String id = target.getId();
                    if ("val1".equals(id) || "val2".equals(id)) {
                        if (target instanceof UIInput) {
                            componentList.add((UIInput) target);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return VisitResult.ACCEPT;
            }
        });
```

so I have (in this case) all 4 components (but let say only those for first tab are invalid).

I'm trying to find a way how to identified which component belong to which tab (not sure whether to rely on a an order in list).

I was trying dynamic ID's, but it's not working, e.g. I added tab name (`tabName`)as attribute and used

```xml
<p:inputText id="#{cc.attr.tabName}-val2" ... />
```

I found no way how to add some custom flag/attribute whatever to be able to link component to a tab.

I was reading that ID can be dynamic once I'd use EL custom function (I mean I can use concatenation), but I was not able to find a resource describing it (I have no `web.xml`).

Code is available in [GitHub](https://github.com/Betlista/SO-FindComponent).

### myTab.xhtml (custom component)

```xml
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="data" required="true" type="betlista.so.pf.findComponent.TabData" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>

    <div class="ui-g">
        <div class="ui-g-12">
            <div class="ui-g-6">
                <p:outputLabel value="Val 1:"/>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-g-6">
                <p:inputText id="val1" value="#{cc.attrs.data.val1}" widgetVar="#{cc.attrs.data.tabName}-val1"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ui-g-12">
            <div class="ui-g-6">
                <p:outputLabel value="Val 2:"/>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-g-6">
                <p:inputText id="val2" readonly="true" value="#{cc.attrs.data.val2}" widgetVar="#{cc.attrs.data.tabName}-val2"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</composite:implementation>
</html>
```

### page.xhtml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:comp="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/comp">

<h:head>
    <h:outputScript library="webjars" name="font-awesome/5.5.0/js/all.js"/>
</h:head>

<h:body styleClass="mainBody">

    <h:form id="form">
        <p:tabView id="tabView" value="#{tabView.tabsData}" var="tabVar">
            <p:tab id="tab" title="#{tabVar.tabName}">
                <comp:myTab data="#{tabVar}" />
            </p:tab>
        </p:tabView>
        <p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{tabView.save()}" process="@form" update="@form" />

        <p:growl id="growl" life="3000"/>
    </h:form>

</h:body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got very confused by debugger...

The simplest solution is to add `label` like this:

```xml
<p:inputText id="val1" value="#{cc.attrs.data.val1}" label="someLabel1" />
```

...what I missed earlier is, that `label` is not a field therefor it was difficult to find it, it is available under `stateHelper`:

[image: debug in IDEA for InputText - stateHelper]

Probably better solution (despite `label` I cannot see in generated HTML) is to use custom attribute like this (I'd bet I tried that as well, apparently not):

```xml
                <p:inputText id="val2" readonly="true" value="#{cc.attrs.data.val2}">
                    <f:attribute name="someAttribute" value="value2" />
                </p:inputText>
```

and it's easily accessible:

[image: debug in IDEA for InputText attributes]